# Canvas stroke line width

Tags: android, canvas, android-canvas, rectangles, stroke

I'm creating a rectangle and it's showing perfectly, but I can't delete the stroke border

```
mPaint = new Paint();
mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
mPaint.setFilterBitmap(true);
mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
mPaint.setStrokeWidth(0.0f);
mPaint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
```

I'm setting the Stroke Width to 0.0f, but it is still showing a really thin line.   How can I delete it?

Comment: You're asking for a style of stroke, and the javadoc says for stroke width: "A value of 0 strokes in hairline mode. Hairlines always draws a single pixel independent of the canva's matrix."  Just pointing this out.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to draw anyway?  Do you have a screenshot or illustration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change `mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);` to `mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);`
and remove the line that sets the stroke width.

see: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.Style.html